# What is the ideal way to modify sub control styles in a custom firemonkey control?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am attempting to develop my first proper custom control for the Firemonkey framework and have ran into what may possibly be an obvious (or not) solution.

Inside my Firemonkey control I have declared `FPanel: TPanel;` which is then created in the constructor and freed in the destructor. The panel is created along with my control when I add it to a new Multi-Device Form without any problems.

By default the `TPanel` has borders around the sides of the control which I do not need in my control.

So my question is, what is the ideal way to remove the borders of a `TPanel` which is child to my custom control? I could not see an obvious property to change, unless I am mistaking I believe we must modify the style of the panel which I assume would be done via a `TStyleBook`.

Am I right then in thinking that I need to add a `TStyleBook` to my control, and from there add the panel to the Style book and modify it this way? Unless I am missing something this seems like a lot of extra work for what should be a very quick and simple change.

Assuming this is the correct way, is there an example of modifying a `TStyleBook` through code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because all Firemonkey controls can be parents, one way is to not use `TPanel` at all and instead replace it with another Firemonkey control such as the `TRectangle` shape.

The `TRectangle` shape can then be customised directly through its properties to remove the border which can be achieved by setting the `Corners` and `Sides` to False.

Additionally if you don't require any borders whatsoever then the `TLayout` control behaves just like a `TPanel` but without the borders.